# SELECT EXISTS vs. LIMIT 1

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I see `SELECT EXISTS` used a lot like:

```
    if db.query("""
        SELECT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM checkout
            WHERE checkout_id = %s
        )
    """ % checkout_id).getresult()[0][0] == 't':
```

vs. what i prefer:

```
    if db.query("""
        SELECT 1 FROM checkout
        WHERE checkout_id = %s
        LIMIT 1
    """ % checkout_id).getresult():
```

Which one is preferred and why?

P.S. i am using Python and PosgreSQL.

```
cert=> explain SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM checkout WHERE checkout_id = 3);
                                      QUERY PLAN                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=4.03..4.03 rows=1 width=0)
   InitPlan
     ->  Index Scan using checkout_pkey on checkout  (cost=0.00..4.03 rows=1 width=0)
           Index Cond: (checkout_id = 3)
(4 rows)

cert=> explain SELECT 1 FROM checkout WHERE checkout_id = 3 limit 1;
                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..4.03 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Index Scan using checkout_pkey on checkout  (cost=0.00..4.03 rows=1 width=0)
         Index Cond: (checkout_id = 3)
(3 rows)
```

My point is, why getting a row from the result and check if it's first column is true, if i can just check if there are any rows at all, meaning the same?

Comment: Definitely not SQL Server. LIMIT 1 tells me this might be mysql (just guessing)

Comment: PostgreSQL generates (nearly) identical execution plans for both versions. So there shouldn't be a difference between them

Comment: Surely mysql ... I think he using php+mysql.

Comment: the `exists` operator can stop at the first row returned, so even for MySQL's optimizer there shouldn't be a difference between the two statements.

Comment: sorry, i thought it's not relevant: i am using Python and PosgreSQL

Comment: You would have to compare to `SELECT COALESCE(SELECT TRUE FROM checkout WHERE checkout_id = %s LIMIT 1), FALSE)` to get matching results. `EXISTS` is clearly the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PostgreSQL seems to clever enough to treat both statements alike as you can clearly see in your execution plans.

My tests with a local table with ~150000 rows and ~100 selected out of that by the condition also show the same behaviour

The bottomline is: it doesn't really matter which one you use, but you should be aware that other DBMS might not behave in the same way.

Answer (score 9):

To my eye the second statement is problematic in that it will not return a row if the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: That's really a true statement.

Comment: I don't know what procedural language this is embedded in (php?), so perhaps an exception is raised by db.query.

Comment: Yes, and that is the idea -- you just check if there are any rows returned. If no rows are returned -- the filter has no records.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `EXPLAIN` you can see that the first statement will execute an additional subquery and the second does not.

That is why I would prefer using `limit` instead of `exists`

Example:

```
explain SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM checkout WHERE id = 3);
explain SELECT 1 FROM checkout WHERE id = 3 limit 1;
```

Comment: That's obhious, you always specify a sunquery to `exists` to check exitence of a rows. Documenation itself says `Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows`