# How to check if query in SqlAlchemy returns empty result?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'd like to perform a query like so:

```
    query = users.select().where(users.column.id == id)
    res = await database.execute(query)
```

I would then like to add some error handling by checking `res`. `if not res` does not seem to be correct. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is there a bias against checking if the res.rowcount is 0? It seems like the most logical solution to me, and it's built-in too.

Comment: @c8999c3f964f64 The bias is that it performs an entire query to get to that rowcount, while in theory it could stop at the very first result. There is no reason to ask you to count all traffic lights in your city when all I want to know is whether you have any at all

Comment: I see that, thanks for explaining. I just didnt think the question asked for "check if a query WOULD return something, instead of doing the complete query". Using your answer below, the worst case is that its doing 99% of a query, then returns true, then you have to do the actual query again, because it didnt finish and could be missing results, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your query, it might be cheaper to wrap it inside a `SELECT EXISTS(...)` than to `SELECT ... LIMIT 1`, as Antonio describes. PostgreSQL probably knows to treat those queries the same, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10600020/5015356), not all DBMS might do so.

The beauty of such a solution is that it exists as soon as it finds any result -- it does as little work as possible and is thus as cheap as possible. In [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html?highlight=exists#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.exists) that would be `sa.select([sa.exists(query)])`

Answer (score 2):

You can try taking first object from your query and checking if it is Null like this

```
result = users.select().where(users.column.id == id).first()
if not result:
    print('query is empty')
```

The other way editing your code would be

```
res = query.first()
```

And then checking if it is Null